# HTML: Update Google Search Title and Summary

Tags: html

I want to change the title and summary of my website on google search results.

Is enough to change the meta-data and title on my html files, and wait few weeks to let google update the results ? (how long does it take on average ?)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is enough to change the meta-data and title on my html files, and wait few weeks to let google update the results ? (how long does it take on average ?)

Basically yes. The time you'll have to wait varies very much from site to site, depending on Page Rank, visitor frequency and other factors. Stack Overflow results are indexed within minutes; smaller sites within days or weeks.

It may also be worth signing up with the [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) to find out how "visible" your site is to the Google bot and when it last dropped by.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's sufficient, but if you want to try to kick-start it a bit you can resubmit your top-level page [here](http://www.google.com/addurl/). You might also consider trying out some of the [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/), which in addition to actual tools also have help entries like these:

- **[Requesting reconsideration of your site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35843&hl=en)**
- **[Changing your site's title and description in search results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35264)**

Answer (score 0):

yes it is enough, make sure if you have any sitemap.xml file then it has to be updated and resubmitted to google. Now a days google takes 3-5 days to crawl your files to new indexing.